# Looping through all the string values of cell by vba

Tags: excel, vba, loops

So this is what I want to do:

For example, in the sheet named "Outputs", the A1 cell input is
= "abcd" & Input!A5 & "efgh",
where Input!A5 is the cell value of the different sheet in the excel file.

I want to make it change so that after executing all the methods after selecting the A1 cell as
= "abcd" & Input!A5 & "efgh", I want to change the A1 cell as, = "abcd" & Input!A6 & "efgh", and then = "abcd" & Input!A7 & "efgh" and so on. (So it's basically replacing the values as A1 to Ai)

I thought of using Replace function, by writing the replacing string as Ai, and replacing i with i +1 by starting with for loop.

But I don't think this is a right method.
Could anyone shed light on how to address this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```
InputWorksheetLastRow = 7 'place here your last row value
Set ws = Worksheets("Input")

For i = 5 To InputWorksheetLastRow
    Worksheets("Outputs").Range("A" & i - 4).Formula = "=" & Chr(34) & "abcd" & Chr(34) & "&Input!" & ws.Cells(i, 1).Address(0, 0) & "&" & Chr(34) & "efgh" & Chr(34)
Next i
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, and it actually works. However, Would there be another efficient way to address this? For some case where I need to replace a lot of cells, this would definitely be tedious.

Comment: Maybe to use the replace function, replacing Ai to A(i+1) and then looping through this.

Comment: @cycla For i = 5 To InputWorksheetLastRow
    `Worksheets("Outputs").Cells(1,1).Formula = "=" & Chr(34) & "abcd" & Chr(34) & "&Input!" & ws.Cells(i, 1).Address(0, 0) & "&" & Chr(34) & "efgh" & Chr(34)
Next i` where Cells(row number, column number)